# Why is #import deprecated?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, android-studio

I understand how `#import` works vs `#include`, the whole "Only include it if it isn't already included" thing. I also understand that Apple is pretty fond of #import for their Objective-C code, so over in Xcode it's not going anywhere and everything's fine.

What I don't get is in other environments like Android Studio, it says that `#import` is deprecated and gives warnings if you use it. Why is that?

It's my understanding that `#import` is functionally different and, in some cases, arguably better than `#include`, depending on what you need. If that's the case, why deprecate a potentially useful tool, especially if there isn't any sign of it being replaced with something better?

Is there some horrendous flaw in it that makes it wholly undesirable to use, or is it fine?

Comment: `#import` isn't valid Java. What are you talking about?

Comment: @Alexander: possibly OP is talking about c/c++ which can be used for Android development as well.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, if you're working with the JNI you can use C++ code with Java.

Answer (score 1):

Because Objective-C is a superset of the C programming language, the `#import` statement is a minor refinement upon C’s `#include` statement. The `#include` statement is very simple; it copies everything it finds in the included file into your code during compilation. This can sometimes cause significant problems. This can creates a loop, and can confuse the compiler. To deal with this, C programmers have to write guards against this type of event from occurring.

When using `#import`, you don’t need to worry about this issue or write header guards to avoid it. However, `#import` is still just a glorified copy-and-paste action, causing slow compilation time among a host of other smaller but still very dangerous issues (such as an included file overriding something you have declared elsewhere in your own code.)

From iOS 7, Apple introduced a new way to import file:

```
@import UIKit;
```

It's a new feature called Modules or "semantic import". Modules are an attempt to get around above issue. They are no longer a copy-and-paste into source code, but a serialized representation of the included files that can be imported into your source code only when and where they’re needed. By using modules, code will generally compile faster, and be safer than using either `#include` or `#import`.

To get more information about this, you can watch [WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/)

Comment: I see, so Apple's own Obj-C "@import" works differently from the ordinary "#import". That's really interesting. I'm not sure if it answers the question, however, of why "#import" is considered deprecated in some environments if it's any kind of improvement over "#include".